# U.K. Student visa application declaration

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, uk-visa

I went for my visa appointment today and the office did not ask me to sign any paper. In my printed visa application, I forgot to sign the declaration on page 2 and 10. But when I remembered after 1-2 hours I went back to them and spoke to their supervisor but he told me not to worry because they only scan the first page which includes the barcode. Does anyone know if It's true? Do they only scan the supporting documents and review the application submitted online????